# Is there a way to assign the class of an R data.table column from within the j part

Tags: r, class, data.table

Suppose I want to set the `class` on all the items in a `data.table` column.  I feel like there should be a way to do this sort of thing from inside the `DT[,j]` part, but it doesn't seem to work.  I have to do it using `$`. Does anyone know why?

```
> DT <- data.table(L = letters, N = 1:26)
> sapply(DT, class)
          L           N 
"character"   "integer" 
> DT[, {class(N) <- "MyClass"}]   # Doesn't work
[1] "MyClass"
> sapply(DT, class)
          L           N 
"character"   "integer" 
> DT[, class(N) <- "MyClass"]    # Doesn't work
[1] "MyClass"
> sapply(DT, class)
          L           N 
"character"   "integer" 
> class(DT$N) <- "MyClass"    # Works
> sapply(DT, class)
          L           N 
"character"   "MyClass"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DT[,N:=as.myclass(N)]
```

Should work